# Java selenium - Can't select date from calendar popup

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, calendar

I'm new to automation with selenium webdriver. I'm trying to book a flight on a travel website. (ryanair.com)

I'm getting stuck with a popup datepicker. I can use .sendkeys to enter the day only, after any field on the date inputs is clicked it triggers the popup calendar to appear so if the format of the inputis dd/mm/yyyy and I want to enter "20042019" it only enters 20 in the dd and then automatically selects the current month and year as autocomplete and opens the calendar popup.

I'ver read a few articles saying that these calendars are usually of two types 
1. iframe
2. datepicker  - I think the one on ryanair is datepickers based on the xpath below

```
//div[@id='datetimepicker_dateview']//table//tbody//td[not(contains(@class,'k-other-month')
```

Maybe that's the wrong xpath? But I think it's correct

I have tried to find the list of dates to book using :

```
   List<WebElement> list_AllDateToBook = driver.findElements(By.xpath()
   System.out.println("size of list is : " + list_AllDateToBook.size() );
   System.out.println("list is : " + list_AllDateToBook );
```

Output is:
size of list is : 0
list is : []

When I use xpath to enter the date of the date field it works for the first input using:

```
WebElement day = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='row-dates-pax']/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/input[1]"));
```

However when I change the xpath to the second input it won't enter the second input(month)

```
WebElement day = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='row-dates-pax']/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/input[2]"));
```

A sample of the datepicker HTML is below (it's too long to add it all!)

```
   <core-datepicker class="start-date" default-date="" start-date="18-03-2019" end-date="28-03-2020" highlight-from="20-03-2019" highlight-to="20-04-2019" end-show="true" fly-out="true" value="dateRange.startDate" cb-event-id="cal-selector:select-start-date" unavailable-dates="dateRange.unavailabiltyStartDates" selected-month-view="dateRange.startDateSelectedMonthView" show-month-toggle="::dateRange.showMonthToggle" show-single-month=""><!----><div ng-class="::{'has-monthly-toggle': isMonthToggleVisible()}"><div bindonce="" class="datepicker-wrapper r scrollable value-selected" ng-class="{ scrollable: !device.isPhone(), mobile: device.isPhone(), 'value-selected': value, 'six-rows': checkIf6Rows()}" style="transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.57, 0.1, 1); transition-duration: 0ms; transform: translate(0px, 0px) translateZ(0px);"><!----><!----><ul ng-if="!device.isPhone()"><!----><li bindonce="" ng-repeat="i in _monthViews" ng-class="{ 'starting-month': checkIfIsSame(getDate(i), highlightFrom, 'month'), 'selected-month': checkIfIsSame(getDate(i), value, 'month'), 'highlight-on': canHighlight(i) }" class="calendar-view starting-month selected-month"><h1 class="month-name">March 2019</h1><ul class="week-days"><!---->
```

I'm really stuck here. Any advice would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Please add the html of the element you are trying to access here

Comment: Have you tried to access particular day in the calendar by 'data-id' attribute? Say //*[@data-id='24-03-2019']

Comment: @SameerArora - the html is too long for the comment box

Comment: @Hairdo please add that in the question only.

Comment: @SameerArora. It seems it's too long for the question section also. Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 58960.

Comment: @Matthewek. Tried that but it's giving the following:  no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"//*[@data-id='24-03-2019']"}                        I'm using driver.findElement(By.id("//*[@data-id='24-03-2019']"));

Comment: Can you please add some HTML into the question, it doesn't have to be the full date picker code, but an example of a couple of the date elements you're trying to select, or if it's a public website you're working on can you provide a link? (You mentioned Ryanair but i can't find elements matching the one in the question on the date picker on the homepage)

Comment: @Hairdo it should be By.xpath not By.id in this case.

Comment: @Matthewek. Unfortunately not working either. WebElement date = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@data-id='24-03-2019']"));
  date.click();

Comment: @Jsmith2800. URL is https://www.ryanair.com/ie/en/

Answer (score 0):

Please try with :

```
li[data-id='12-04-2019'] span
```

Note: Add till span tag. Just tried via console and working.

```
document.querySelector("li[data-id='12-04-2019'] span").click()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately i'm getting the following: 
   invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression li[data-id='12-04-2019'] span because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string 'li[data-id='12-04-2019'] span' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: I'm using  WebElement date = driver.findElement(By.xpath("li[data-id='12-04-2019'] span"));
  date.click();

Comment: The website is full of these popup elements that I will have to select from. I don't know how to handle these types of elements but it seem I really need to!

Comment: Provided path is CSS one. For xpath, please use driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@data-id='12-04-2019']/span"))

Comment: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//li[@data-id='12-04-2019']/span"}

Comment: Hope date picker popup opened before performing date click option.

Comment: yes the popup is open. But it cannot be located or clicked at all it seems. I even tried doing this with selenium ide to check what it's using to locate this element and it can't find it either, even thought he popup is open. Am I calling it the right name when i say "datepicker"? Could this be something else?

Comment: Then try with Java script option, JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("document.querySelector('li[data-id=\'12-04-2019\'] span').click();");

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code from python. Please see the approach that I followed and simulate the same in java.

```
import os
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


def get_full_path_to_folder(folderName):
    folders = os.path.abspath(os.pardir).split(os.sep)
    folderPath = ''
    for folder in folders:
        if folderPath == '':
            folderPath = folder
        else:
            folderPath = folderPath + "\\" +folder
        if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(folderPath, folderName)):
            return os.path.join(folderPath, folderName)
            break
def wait_for_element_present(locator_type, locator):
    if locator_type == 'xpath':
        return (wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, locator))))
    elif locator_type == "css":
        return (wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, locator))))

chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.path.join(get_full_path_to_folder('drivers'), "chromedriver.exe"))
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
url = "https://www.ryanair.com/us/en/"
# go to url
driver.get(url)
#================ you should focus the below code=======================
# close the cookie pop up, otherwise the date and country elements not interable for selenium for interaction
wait_for_element_present('css',".cookie-popup__close").click()
#click on destination edit box
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".route-selector-destination").click()
# select desitnation country
destiCountry = wait_for_element_present('xpath',"//div[@ng-repeat='option in $ctrl.firstOptions track by option.id' and text()=' Italy']")
destiCountry.click()
#select destination airport
desti = wait_for_element_present('xpath',"//span[contains(@ng-if,'secondOptionsEnabled') and .='Naples']")
desti.click()
# select outbound date
dateEle = wait_for_element_present('css',"li[data-id='24-03-2019']")
if dateEle.value_of_css_property('font-size') == '15px':
    dateEle.click()
#select in bound date
dateEle = wait_for_element_present('css',"li[data-id='20-04-2019']")
if dateEle.value_of_css_property('font-size') == '15px':
    dateEle.click()
#hurry, the date selection is successful.
```

Comment: thanks for your help. Unfortunately this isn't the issue. The font size is 15px. There are flights available on those dates, if I enter it manually into the website and click next, all is fine.

Comment: Sorry, that mean you are able to select the date in both the fields but not able to navigate to next page when clicked on `Let's go` button? or selecting dates with automation is not allowing you to navigate to next page?

Comment: I'm not able to select any date. I cannot seem to interact with the datepicker at all. I can click on the dd or mm  or yyyy fields and this will enable the popup. But after this I cannot interact with the calendar popup at all. Or enter any date in the input fields

Comment: Are you able to select the destination?

Comment: I can select destination only by sendkeys and entering destination country that has only one available airport. I cannot select from a list of airports

Comment: ok. Let me try in python, I don't have Java selenium setup on my machine. Will get to know if there are issue at least by working on python code.

Comment: Updated the working code in python. Please post me if you get any hurdles in java.

Comment: Thanks so much, that works for me! But I have a (probably) stupid/rookie quesion. How did you identify the cssSelectors and By.xpath ("//span[contains(@ng-if,'secondOptionsEnabled') and .='Naples']")));     I could not identify this and it something I think I should understand

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190261/discussion-between-supputuri-and-hairdo).

Comment: Cool. You can use the Inspect in the chrome dev tools. Always first type the string that you are trying find in html, then you will see the matching html tag. Then develop the xpath/css.